# Clojure - leiningen jar file alternate download location

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I am trying to get leiningen on a development machine behind a firewall that does not allow access to github.  Is there an alternate location that hosts the latest leiningen jar file?

As of posting this question, the file is called leiningen-2.5.0-standalone.jar and is available on github at this link:

https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/releases/download/2.5.0/leiningen-2.5.0-standalone.jar

Comment: Why don't you get it from another pc on your local network and copy it through `scp` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Examining the `lein` script reveals, that you could simply copy the script to a place on the executable path, and copy the `leiningen-2.5.0-standalone.jar` to `$HOME/.lein/self-installs/`.

Try downloading both files to another box and `scp` them to the development machine.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  That's what I ended up doing.  I downloaded the files on another machine, zipped them and mailed them over to the box where I was trying to install leiningen.